# Regex search for string that contains + or # using Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm doing some string search using Java Pattern class.
I'm trying to match string (txt) that contains "c++" or "c#" inside using java Pattern class.

```
String txt="c++ / c# developer";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\b(c\\+\\+|c#)\\b.*" , Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
while (m.find()) {
...
   break;
}
```

m.find is always false
What am i doing wrong?
Thanks
Ofer

Comment: Put a Sample text and sample result.

Answer (score 6):

`\\b` is a word boundary. Which means it matches between a word and a non-word character. `+` and `#` are both non-word characters, so you require `c++` or `c#` to be followed by a letter, digit or underscore. Try removing the `\\b` or replacing it with a `\\B` (which would require that there is another non-word character after the `+` or `#`).

Note that, when you are using `find`, you don't need the `.*` either. `find` will happily return partial matches. Your pattern would give you the last occurrence of either `c++` or `c#` in the first capturing group. If that is not what you want, remove the parentheses and wildcards.

[Working demo.](http://fiddle.re/tn5j6)

**EDIT:** If you are adding other alternatives that **do** end in word characters (like `java`). The cleanest solution would be not to use `\\b` or `\\B` at all, but create your own boundary condition using a negative lookahead. This way you are simply saying "match if there is no word character next":

```
\\b(c\\+\\+|c#|java)(?!\\w)
```

[Working demo.](http://fiddle.re/xkfg6)

Comment: Thanks, when I use the pattern \\b(c\\+\\+|c#|java)\\B it now finds c++ or c#, but when i try to match the string "java" it failed (it worked before when i used \\b at the end). Is there any way in regex to mix both approaches in one regex pattern?

Comment: @user2022561 I've adjusted my answer to accommodate that

Comment: I used the second option and it now working perfectin all cases. Thanks alot for your help

Comment: @user2022561 please consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. this will show future visitors that (and how) the problem has been solved (and give me some credit and a little to you as well)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `^.*c(\+{2}|\#).*$`.  It says find a `c` followed by either 2 `+`'s or a `#`.  You can see an example [here](http://rubular.com/r/AHY2Wi7fY2).

Comment: you should at least provide the demo link in a tester that uses the appropriate engine: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: @m.buettner bookmarked and I'll use that for all Java regex examples in the future.  Rubular has been the cleanest/neatest one I have used, so I use that one for the quick examples.  Thank you.